# Process all virtual sub pages on parent page

Tags: permalinks, filters

My parent page: http://example.com/id

Virtual pages are:

- http://example.com/id/1563
- http://example.com/id/john/5896
- http://example.com/id/jack-miami/3054

I use shortcode in **parent page** that gets id number from URL then show the result.

Now all above pages show 404 errors. Is it possible to use the parent page for showing all pages with links containing *example.com/id/*

I used this but it does not work:

```
function edit_the_permalink($url){
    if(strpos($url, get_site_url().'/id/') !== false){
        $url = get_site_url().'/id/';
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'edit_the_permalink');
```

Answer (score 0):

`add_filter('the_permalink')`, is the wrong tool for the job, it gets you the [full permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) for the current post or a specific post ID.

It seems like the proper approach would be to use a rewrite rule:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($vars){
      $vars[] = 'id';
      return $vars;
});
add_rewrite_rule('id\/([\w\-]+)\/?', 'index.php?id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

CAVEAT: I haven't tried this, and `id` might be a reserved name in the rewrite rule.

But, this is the general idea for getting virtual subpages from a real parent page.